# In CodeIgniter, default controller is always loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to migrate my CI 1.7.2 application into 2.0.2. I have gotten to the point where my default controller and page are loaded correct. Yey!

However, the default controller is all that’s ever loaded. Example:

```
myapp/ -> loads default controller (one)
myapp/one -> loads default controller (one)
myapp/two -> loads default controller (one)
myapp/three -> loads default controller (one)
```

My `.htaccess` is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My `config.php` is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myapp/branches/Source%20Code/';
$config['index_page']     = '';
$config['uri_protocol']   = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

By the way, I’ve tried all other possible values for `URI PROTOCOL` and they give me `“The page you requested was not found.”`

Finally, my `routes.php` is:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "one";
```

I also tried changing default_controller to "two" and it correctly loads the "two" controller. But when the default_controller is "one" and I type in "myapp/two" in the address bar, it still loads "one"

What am I missing? :)

Comment: Important question: Have you followed ***all*** the [upgrade steps](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) so far? This problem sounds vaguely familiar and I think it is something simple with Codeigniter...

Comment: According to this thread, http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/187501/ ,  in the official forums, you already have this solved?

Comment: @Repox: yes but the solution is different from what I hoped for. I'm uncomfortable using QUERY_STRING. i was looking for something similar to tgriesser's answer below.

Comment: Why are you 'uncomfortable' with that? It seems illogical.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an htaccess problem. Try changing your mod rewrite to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myapp/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and then change `$config['uri_protocol']` to `AUTO`.

Comment: thanks but that didn't solve it. actually i changed the base_url in this question for simplicity. but the actual base_url is really as it is now, above (edited). so i tried your suggestion and it didn't work. i also tried `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myapp/branches/Source%20Code/index.php/$1 [L]` and still didn't work. any other ideas? :)

Comment: The best way to determine if it's an htaccess problem is to change your index_page back to index.php and see if the controllers load correctly. if they do, then it's htaccess, if they don't then it's something in your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think  uri_protocol => 'PATH_INFO' is not supported

So, change trying to

> **$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';** // application/config/config.php

then,
in your , .htaccess change the

> RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]

to

> **RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]**